# Mindbody API: How to pass a list of values to a parameter in postman?

Tags: postman, mindbody

I am new to API integration and working on a project associated with Mindbody API.
Take API documentation for getting clients' services as an example, as the picture shows, I had to specify the client's ID and program's ID to get the data. But this approach **is limited to a single service related to a client only**. However, what if I want ALL the services that ALL the clients ever had? What would be the most efficient approach to have a list for the parameters, ClientID and ProgramID?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NklUU.png)
(Mindbody API Documentation: https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Clients endpoint](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6#get-clients) to get the clients, then iterate through that list requesting all [ClientServices](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6#get-client-services) for each Client.

Note that the requests could be paginated, so you may need to make multiple requests to get all the Clients and then multiple ClientServices requests per client, depending on how the limits are all configured.

Comment: Can you please specify how to iterate through the list?